# Python nested for loop interpretation

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this following problem from a book I’m learning from and I'd like to know how you would interpret this code to get to the answer (14) because I’m having a hard time getting there.
I understand the concept of *for* loops but this nested one got me good:

When the looping completes, what number will display?

```
outer_loop_total = 0
inner_loop_total = 0
countries = ["Albania", "Morocco", "Brazil", "Denmark"]
capitals = ["Tel Aviv", "Abuja", "Brasília", "Islamabad"]
for country_to_check in countries:
  outer_loop_total += 1
  for city_to_check in capitals:
    inner_loop_total += 1
    if country_to_check == "Brazil" and city_to_check == "Brasília":
      print(outer_loop_total + inner_loop_total)
```

Comment: The usual method is by adding some `print()` statements at interesting points in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop gets executed everytime the outer loop gets executed.
For that `outer_loop_total` gets incremented until `Brazil` has reached. `inner_loop_total` gets incremented until `Brasilia` + x times it takes to reach `Brazil`.

Lets calc (`* 1` stands for your incremented number):

- `outer_loop_total`: 3 * 1
- `inner_loop_total`: ((2 * 4) + 3) * 1
- **Result = `outer_loop_total` + `inner_loop_total` = 3 + 11 = 14**

##### Why (2 * 4) + 3?

Until `Morocco` in `countries` (which is 2 times `2 * ..`) it goes until `Islamabad` in `capitals` (which is 4 times `.. 4`). 
For the last one, when it reaches `Brasil` in `countries`, it only goes until `Brasília` (which is 3 times -> `+ 3`) .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry now I editted. You will see 14 number as an output because you have two loops. outer_loop_total will be 3 and inner_loop_total  will be 11. You have 4 countries in your countries list. Your outer for loop will iterate in countries list orderly. For each country iterated , you iterate in all capitals in capital list. When your current country is "Brazil" and when your current capital is "Brasilia" you will see the output.